# redirects using htmlspecialchars/htmlentities

Tags: php, xss, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

I have this kind fo redirects now

```
Redirect::to(htmlspecialchars('home.php'));
```

but when I type this on my home.php: `/%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('hacked')%3C/script%3E`

it results like this:
[image]

but why ? they said that it will converted so the exploit attempt will be a failure, but why in mine it is not ?

Answer (score 0):

`htmlspecialchars` encodes special characters to their HTML equivalent in a string which is passed by argument.
Your Code

```
Redirect::to(htmlspecialchars('home.php'));
```

only encodes the string `home.php`and pass it to the `Redirect::To`-Function and does not use htmlspecialchars on the output of the whole page.

To solve this, you have to use it on every output in `home.php` like this:

```
<?php
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
?>
```

(Example from: http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)